# ERROR in /home/lyffy/ngproject/cfp1/src/app/skeleton/skeleton.component.ts (2,8): Module '"./lodash/index"' has no default export.

Tags: angular

**ERROR in /home/lyffy/ngproject/cfp1/src/app/skeleton/skeleton.component.ts (2,8): Module '"/home/lyffy/ngproject/cfp1/node_modules/@types/lodash/index"' has no default export**. what's the solution guys please !!!!!

Comment: Probably you are looking for lodash-ts

Comment: @yursui yes but when i try to import lodash i get that error and i don't know what is problem